# Sitecore Publish/Unpublish automatically

Tags: sitecore

I am using Sitecore 9.1 and I set future publish/unpublish dates for some of the items.
I found two articles to do this:

This article talks about

```
1. Download the AUTOMATED PUBLISHER module from the Sitecore Marketplace.
 
2. Have your Sitecore implementers write your own custom code that is triggered by a Sitecore Task.
```

https://www.techguilds.com/Blog/2018/11/scheduled-and-advanced-publishing-with-sitecore-part-2

and

This article, which advises to do it by patching values in the config file:

```
<agent type="Sitecore.Tasks.PublishAgent" method="Run" interval="00:00:00">
    <param desc="source database">master</param>
    <param desc="target database">web</param>
    <param desc="mode (full or smart or incremental)">incremental</param>
    <param desc="languages">en, da</param>
</agent>
```

https://community.sitecore.net/developers/f/8/t/5496

Is auto-publishing built OOB in any version  (in my case 9.1) ?
If not, which of the above would be the preferred way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

From another post, confirmed that you can use the config option. Tested it out and it works.